# SQL Different query depending on the if result

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to do a query that depending on the char_length of one parameter should select one table or another. It should be something like this but I know that is not correct at all and there are syntax errors which I can't find.

```
SELECT IF (
CHAR_LENGTH('var44') < 3,
name FROM nets WHERE code = 'var44',
name FROM variable WHERE id = (SELECT SUBSTRING('var44',4)) 
);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You should do this in PHP and send either one or the other query. Especially since "var44" is hard coded and does not come from another MySQL table.

Answer (score 1):

Would that be a solution for you:

```
select name from nets WHERE code = 'var44' and CHAR_LENGTH('var44') < 3
union
select name FROM variable WHERE id = (SELECT SUBSTRING('var44',4)) and CHAR_LENGTH('var44') >= 3
```

or is the `if` statement forced?

Answer (score 0):

As GhostGambler said, why not do this with php?

```
if (strlen($var44)<3) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM nets WHERE code = '$var44'");
} else {
    $var44 = substring($var44, 4);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM variable WHERE id = '$var44'");
}
```